# How to add scrollbar in dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I want to add a scrollbar in dropdown menu

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-scrollbar">                            
    <!-- <li><a href="#"></a></li> -->

    {% for table_name in obj %}
     <option>{{ table_name.table_name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}

    <!-- <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li> -->
</ul>
```

I tried this css but it's not working. I know it is a duplicate question, but I tried the css from the SQ answer and still is not working, maybe there is something I'm missing?

```css
.dropdown-scrollbar
{
    height: 50px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: try to remove dropdown-menu class it will work fine :)

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot style the default browser dropdown. You might want to look at a JS and CSS solution. Here is one that I found - https://dev.to/emmawedekind/creating-a-custom-accessible-drop-down-3gmo

Comment: @Miky u sure? ._. it just place the item outside the box hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of specifying x-axis and y-axis specifically you can only write overflow as it will automatically takes and adjust both the axis.

You can also use **overflow: auto** instead of **overflow: scroll** the reason is that in **scroll** (Setting the overflow value of a box to scroll will hide the content from rendering outside the box, but will offer scrollbars to scroll the interior of the box to view the content),

**auto** ( it solves the problem of getting scrollbars when you don't need them. The scrollbars will only show up if there is content that actually breaks out of the element).

I have updated the code and it works fine just have a look.

```css
.dropdown-scrollbar
{
    height: 50px;
    overflow: scroll;

}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-scrollbar">

                            <!-- <li><a href="#"></a></li> -->
                               {% for table_name in obj %}
                                <option>{{ table_name.table_name }}</option>
                              {% endfor %}                          
                            <!-- <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li> -->
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add max-height instead of height to your .dropdown-scrollbar or dropdown-menu class:

```
  .dropdown-scrollbar{
    max-height: 50px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```
.dropdown-scrollbar {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```